# Is there a simple and automatic way to create halos around multiple (existing) arrows in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

I am looking for a way for **all** existing black arrows in my illustration to have a white halo to stand out against a colorful background in Illustrator. I would also like the halo to be easily changeable for all arrows (like when using graphic styles).

Theoretical solutions:

1. Adding an additional stroke helps for ordinary lines, but does not outline the arrowhead.
2. Copying an arrow, placing it in the back, slightly enlarging it and making white will surely work, but is tedious. Also, it cannot be saved as a graphic style, so cannot be automatically applied to the existing arrows (you will have to copy the one you created).

As you see, these theoretical solutions do not work.
So, the question is is there **a simple and automatic** way to create halos for multiple existing arrows?

Comment: The truth is there's no easy answer here if using the Stroke Panel arrowheads. You can expand the artwork, but you'll have to do that for all arrows. You can group and *then* apply a stroke to the group, but that can appear "wonky" depending upon the arrowhead and stroke weight.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/create-drop-shadow.html or https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/drop-shadows-glows-feathering.html Change the color to white, and the blend mode to normal. Play with the values.

Comment: Help files are of no use here. The issue is the arrowhead. I suggest you all try it yourself... there's no easy way to add a glow or stroke to a path with an arrowhead, unless you expand appearance first.

Comment: @Scott So, I believe the solution is not to use standard path arrowheads and create my own arrows as shapes? That should both normal double strokes or shadows/glows, which would outline the whole arrow. However, I will have to copy the new arrow shape and replace all the old arrows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of how the arrowhead for strokes feature works, there's no easy solution to getting a hard-edged halo here and retain the existing art as it is.

[image]

If you group the stroke/arrowhead and *then* apply a second stroke to the *group* it still looks wrong.

[image]

The best solution may be to **select all the strokes/arrow** and use `Object > Expand Appearance`. *Then* you can add an additional stroke to one stroke/arrow group, configure it and save as a Graphic Style. And *then* reselect all the other strokes/arrow groups and apply that *same* Graphic style.

Comment: Actually, it's a very nice idea with expanding, but I believe after expanding you get a group stroke+shape and you won't be able to apply a new stroke to them straight away, will you? Shouldn't you first combine them into one shape so as not to have artifacts at the arrowhead-path connection point?

Comment: Yes. You can apply a stroke to the group like my second screen shot. It won't have the extra weight around the arrowhead after expanding.

Comment: Ah, I see, you propose to expand other arrows as well. Well, it seems to work. At small stroke weights the result is a bit bizarre, but greater stroke weights look quite as expected. I have a feeling that this may be the simplest solution. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help. :)

Comment: @scott you dont have to expand you can use a layer (the ball next to layer name) effect where contents is first then you make a stroke and apply outline stroke and outline to the troke. Does same thing as expanding but is not destructive lines are still lines.

Comment: @joojaa Expand and Expand Appearance are different. I suggested Expanding *Appearance* not simply "Expanding"

Comment: @Scott yes yes. Still same thing remains you dont need to destroy the lines to get the line thickness around the lines with a simple appearance sonce there is a near equivalent action for appearances of layers

Comment: @Scott see: http://i.imgur.com/66IpmL3.gif

Comment: Good point @joojaa I tested pathfinder but I didn't test that. Will update this answer as soon as I can. Unless you'd like to post that as an answer.

Comment: @Scott You update, your post is as good as mine. Im busy all day keeping exams

Comment: Actually @Joojaa that doesn't work either [As Seen Here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKRbO.jpg) the same issue arises with an uneven width on the additional stroke. I think your screen shot shows it working because you are applying the stroke to the **layer** and **not the object**. Applying effects/strokes, etc  at the **layer level** is not something I ever do, or suggest doing because there are often bugs when applying things at the layer level.

Comment: no it would not work unless you apply to layers lr groups. Its not buggy but misunderstood because its more complex.

Comment: Joojaa.. it's buggy. I've filed many, many bugs with Adobe due to layer-level effects.

Answer (score 1):

Select your arrow, hit effect, hit stylize, hit outer glow, turn on preview and adjust the settings until you're happy with it.

Comment: Thanks, but like Scott shows, I am afraid you cannot achieve a sharp boundary for the glow, can you?

Comment: @Szczypawka you didn't ask for "sharp boundaries" you asked for a Halo. I've never heard of anyone referring to a Halo as something sharp.

Comment: You are right. That's a matter of taste. I believe your solution may be useful for someone. I have tested both. Somehow I decided that I prefer my arrows to have a sharp boundary.

Comment: @Szczypawka that's fine, I was more hinting at the idea you might want to edit your question... and that I wouldn't have left this answer had I known you wanted a sharp boundary :)

Comment: Well, but as I say, now that you have left it, the question itself is OK, since I've got answers for both sharp and not sharp boundaries. :) And the "halo" is a standard term used for such arrows appearance, isn't it?

Comment: @Szczypawka someone else can correct me, but no its not a standard term. Not one I've ever heard of. Halo is a ring of light around and usually behind an object. Light doesn't generally have hard edges, and when Halo's have been drawn with hard edges such as religious iconography it is drawn as a circle. I've never once heard of an arrow's stroke being referred to as a Halo. Again, someone else might know otherwise, maybe its even a language difference.

Comment: @Szczypawka we're discussing it in the chat room right now if you'd care to join -- http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't join you in the chat. But I am still thinking about the "halo" and I am starting to agree that soft edges may indeed look more natural than iconographic hard edges. So you are probably right... Hard edges look a bit weird in a scheme.

Comment: @Szczypawka haha no worries